# Java - HashMap values - volatile

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap

I have a situation where I have N threads that do same the job, and one thread X that does something different.

Each thread N reads/writes into a static object which is of a class (called MMLCounter) which is wrapper around HashMap, and each thread works with different key/value pair of that HashMap, so all threads read/write values into the HashMap at the same time.
Thread X periodically needs to access all values, and while it's accessing them (from the moment it accesses first value till the moment it accesses the last value, none of the other N threads may change the values in HashMap).

HashMap is initialized and key/values added to it by threads during thread creation at the start of program execution, and later no new key/values are added, only values in HashMap change.

Because of this I didn't use ConcurrentHashMap or synchronized functions, but instead I created a wrapper class around HashMap, which additionally has a flag which signals the N threads are they allowed to change the values, and this flag is changed exclusively by thread X.

This way all N threads can work with HashMap in parallel, but when thread X starts its work only it can work with the HashMap until it finishes.

My question here is do I need to declare anything as volatile (for example values in HashMap), and if yes, what and how?

Thing what I would like to avoid (don't know if it is possible that it happens) is that one of the N threads changes a value in HashMap, but that change of value is only reflected in local cached memory of that thread, and when thread X reads that value from HashMap it will read it from its local cached memory which is not in sync with local cached memory of the other N thread, meaning it will have a old value.

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ProtocolException { 

    int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 400; 

    List<Future<?>> futureList = new ArrayList<Future<?>>(); 
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS+1);
    futureList.add(executor.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() { 
                int measureInterval = 10000;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(measureInterval);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
                System.out.println("--> MML rate is : " + MMLGenerator.MML_COUNTER.getMMLRate(measureInterval/1000) + " MML per second.");
        }
    }));

    //create and start sending threads. 
    for (int threadNmbr = 0; threadNmbr < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; threadNmbr++) {
        futureList.add(executor.submit(new Thread(new MMLGenerator(threadNmbr))));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 

    //wait for threads to finish. 
    for (Future<?> future : futureList) { 
        try { 
            future.get(); 
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        } 
        catch (ExecutionException e) { 
            throw (RuntimeException) e.getCause(); 
        } 
    } 
    executor.shutdown();
} 

class MMLGenerator implements Runnable {

    public static volatile MMLCounter MML_COUNTER = new MMLCounter();
    private int threadNmbr = 0;

    public MMLGenerator(int threadNmbr) {
        this.threadNmbr = threadNmbr;
        MMLGenerator.MML_COUNTER.put(this.threadNmbr, 0);

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(RUN_ACTIVE) {
            MML_COUNTER.increaseCounter(this.threadNmbr);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class MMLCounter {

  private Map<Integer,Integer> MMLCounter = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
  private boolean MMLCounterLocked = false;

  public Integer get(Integer key) {
      return this.MMLCounter.get(key);
  }

  public Integer put(Integer key, Integer value) {
      while (this.MMLCounterLocked) {
          try {
              Thread.sleep(100);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
      return this.MMLCounter.put(key, value);
  }

  public void increaseCounter(Integer key) {
      while (this.MMLCounterLocked) {
          try {
              Thread.sleep(100);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
      this.MMLCounter.put(key,this.MMLCounter.get(key).intValue() + 1);
  }

  public int getMMLRate(int measurementTime) {
      this.MMLCounterLocked = true;
      int MMLCounterSum = 0;
      for (Integer counterID : this.MMLCounter.keySet()) {
          int counter = this.MMLCounter.get(counterID);
          MMLCounterSum += counter;
          this.MMLCounter.put(counterID, 0);
      }
      this.MMLCounterLocked = false;
      return MMLCounterSum/measurementTime;
  }
```

}

---

### AFTER MODIFICATION

Thank you everybody for help.
I just now read `ReentrantReaderWriterLock` description and that really is what I need. Below is the modified code.

However, I still have two questions:

1) Why do I need to use also `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of `HashMap` if I protected critical part of codes with `ReentrantReaderWriterLock`?

2) This usage of `ReentrantReaderWriterLock` will only substitute from my previous implementation the usage of flag which I now see was not done correctly. However, I still have the problem of value objects in `HashMap` not being volatile, so different threads will each have their own locally cached copy of a value which is not in sync with locally cached copy of the value from other threads?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ProtocolException { 

    int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 400; 

    List<Future<?>> futureList = new ArrayList<Future<?>>(); 
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS+1);
    futureList.add(executor.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() { 
                int measureInterval = 10000;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(measureInterval);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
                System.out.println("--> MML rate is : " + MMLGenerator.counter.getMMLRate(measureInterval/1000) + " MML per second.");
        }
    }));

    //create and start sending threads. 
    for (int threadNmbr = 0; threadNmbr < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; threadNmbr++) {
        futureList.add(executor.submit(new Thread(new MMLGenerator(threadNmbr))));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 

    //wait for threads to finish. 
    for (Future<?> future : futureList) { 
        try { 
            future.get(); 
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        } 
        catch (ExecutionException e) { 
            throw (RuntimeException) e.getCause(); 
        } 
    } 
    executor.shutdown();
} 

class MMLGenerator implements Runnable {

    public static MMLCounter counter = new MMLCounter();
    private int threadNmbr = 0;

    public MMLGenerator(int threadNmbr) {
        this.threadNmbr = threadNmbr;
        MMLCounter.counter.put(this.threadNmbr, 0);

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(RUN_ACTIVE) {
            MMLCounter.counter.increaseCounter(this.threadNmbr);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class MMLCounter {

  private Map<Integer,Integer> counter = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
  public static final ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock(true);

  public Integer put(Integer key, Integer value) {
      lock.readLock().lock();
      Integer oldValue = this.counter.put(key, value);
      lock.readLock().unlock();
      return oldValue;
  }

  public void increaseCounter(Integer key) {
      lock.readLock().lock();
      this.counter.put(key,this.counter.get(key).intValue() + 1);
      lock.readLock().unlock();
  }

  public int getMMLRate(int measurementTime) {
      lock.writeLock().lock();
      int counterSum = 0;
      for (Integer counterID : this.counter.keySet()) {
          counterSum += this.counter.get(counterID);;
          this.counter.put(counterID, 0);
      }
      lock.writeLock().unlock();
      return counterSum/measurementTime;
  }
}
```

---

### AFTER 2nd MODIFICATION

I now figured out that logic I need to implement requires me to manipulate several counters, not just one, from multiple threads, and each thread at any time can change any counter.
Below is my implementation, but I'm not certain if I in a good way in regards to performance and data consistency.

I except to have random number of counters (number of counters will be know at start of execution) which will be identified by String value, and each Counter must count two values (first value will always increase, a second value only sometimes, but if they increase they need to increase at the same time). When I need to have sum of each Counter, I need fetch both Counter values in an atomic operation, and also from the time I fetch the first Counter till the time I fetch last Counter, none of the Counters may be changed by other threads.

For demonstration purposes, as Counter identification (key in HashMap) I took String value of counter's ordinal number, and to determine which Counter needs to increased in each iteration of each thread, as well as determining if just one or both values of Counter need to increase, I used Random generator.

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 

    int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 400;


    MMLGenerator.counterNmbr(2);
    List<Future<?>> futureList = new ArrayList<Future<?>>(); 
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS+1); 

    futureList.add(executor.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() { 
            while(true)
            {
                int measureInterval = 10;
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(measureInterval);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                MMLGenerator.lock.writeLock().lock();
                for (String counterId : MMLGenerator.counter.keySet()) {
                    MMLCounterSimple counter = MMLGenerator.counter.get(counterId).getCountAndReset();
                    System.out.println("--> For counter " + counterId + " total is : " + counter.getTotal() + ", and failed is : " + counter.getFailed());
                }
                MMLGenerator.lock.writeLock().unlock();
            }
        }
    }));

    //create and start sending threads. 
    for (int threadNmbr = 0; threadNmbr < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; threadNmbr++) {
        futureList.add(executor.submit(new Thread(new MMLGenerator())));
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 

    //wait for threads to finish. 
    for (Future<?> future : futureList) { 
        try { 
            future.get(); 
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        } 
        catch (ExecutionException e) { 
            throw (RuntimeException) e.getCause(); 
        } 
    } 
    executor.shutdown();
} 



class MMLGenerator implements Runnable {

    public static volatile HashMap<String, MMLCounter> counter = new HashMap<String, MMLCounter>();
    public static final ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock(true);


    public static void counterNmbr(int counterNmbr) {
        lock.writeLock().lock();
        for(int i = 0; i < counterNmbr; i++) {
            counter.put(new Integer(i).toString(), new MMLCounter());
        }
        lock.writeLock().unlock();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(RUN_PROVISIONING) {
            lock.readLock().lock();
            String counterID = new Integer(new Random().nextInt(counter.size())).toString();
            long failedInc = 0;
            if (new Random().nextInt(2) == 0) {
                failedInc = 1;
            }
            counter.get(counterID).increaseCounter(failedInc);
            lock.readLock().unlock();
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}


public class MMLCounter {

    private volatile long total = 0;
    private volatile long failed = 0;
    public static final ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock(true);


    public synchronized void increaseCounter(long failedInc) {
        lock.writeLock().lock();
        total++;;
        failed = failed + failedInc;
        lock.writeLock().unlock();
    }

    public synchronized MMLCounterSimple getCountAndReset() {
        lock.writeLock().lock();
        MMLCounterSimple simpleCounter = new MMLCounterSimple(total, failed);
        total = 0;
        failed = 0;
        lock.writeLock().unlock();
        return simpleCounter;
    }

}


public class MMLCounterSimple {

    private long total = 0;
    private long failed = 0;

    public MMLCounterSimple(long total, long failed) {
        this.total = total;
        this.failed = failed;
    }

    public long getTotal() {
        return this.total;
    }

    public long getFailed() {
        return this.failed;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of the map value? It could make a difference to the answer. Also, please remove all code not relevant to the question. For example, show just the few lines around updating the map etc. We don't need or want to see the whole class (which has lots of stuff irrelevant to the question)

Comment: Value in map is Integer.

Comment: Btw. I removed the irrelevant code.

Comment: My guess is you've done some .net/c#? In java, the convention is to use leading lowercase names for methods, fields, variables and parameters. Only class names start with a capital letter. It's quite confusing for us java folks when reading your code, eg we assume `MMLCounter` is a class, when it's actually a field. Better to name it `mmlCounter`, or just `counter` (since there is no other counter in your class)

Comment: Do you need to track the counts for each individual thread? Or just the sum for all threads? In other words, do you use the `get()` method of `MMLCounter`, or just `getMMLRate()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, this isn't guaranteed to work as you expect. There's no synchronization point between the writes performed by the N threads and the read performed by the X thread. Even the `MMLCounterLocked` flag could be ignored by writers.

In addition to making your code work correctly, using higher-level concurrency tools like [`ConcurrentMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) will drastically simplify your code.

---

Since you only require the sum, a [`LongAccumulator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAccumulator.html) will suffice, and it makes the code very simple and safe.

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
    throws Exception
  {
    int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 400;
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);
    LongAccumulator sum = new LongAccumulator(Long::sum, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; ++i) {
      executor.submit(new MMLGenerator(sum));
      TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(50); /* Why??? */
    }
    int interval = 10;
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(interval);
    long rate = sum.getThenReset() / interval;
    System.out.println("--> MML rate is : " + rate + " MML per second.");
    executor.shutdownNow();
  }

  private static final class MMLGenerator
    implements Runnable
  {

    private final LongAccumulator counter;

    MMLGenerator(LongAccumulator counter)
    {
      this.counter = counter;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
      while (true) {
        counter.accumulate(1);
        try {
          TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException shutdown) {
          break;
        }
      }
    }

  }
```

---

As for your two new questions:

1. "Why do I need to use also `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of `HashMap` if I protected critical part of codes with `ReentrantReaderWriterLock`?"

You *didn't* protect the critical part with a read-write lock. You are acquiring the *read* lock when you *write* the table, and the *write* lock when you *read* it. The behavior of `HashMap` isn't defined under concurrent modification. You could cause threads that are using the table to hang.

Also, you should use a `try-finally` construct to ensure that you unlock regardless of any errors that occur.

If you used a `ConcurrentMap`, threads could update without acquiring a lock on the entire table, which is what you'll be doing when you apply the read-write lock correctly.

2. "This usage of `ReentrantReaderWriterLock` will only substitute from my previous implementation the usage of flag which I now see was not done correctly. However, I still have the problem of value objects in `HashMap` not being `volatile`, so [will] different threads … each have their own locally cached copy of a value which is not in sync with locally cached copy of the value from other threads?"

No, `Lock` acquisition does synchronize with other threads, and changes by other threads that happen before the lock is acquired will be visible. If you fixed your locking, the `HashMap` would work correctly, but it would do so by locking the entire table during updates.

Comment: Hi erickson, regarding your question, I just need sum of all threads, but I used HashMap with key/value pair for each thready so each thread could write in parallel the count, and then only when I need the total sum I would calculate it during which other threads would not be able to modify their counter. If there's a better/faster way, I'm open to it. I put in my question modified code which uses `ReentrantReaderWriterLock`, along two additional questions. Do you think that is enough of should I and why additionally use `ConcurrentHashMap`?

Comment: @Xyster I updated my answer with an example. `ReentrantReaderWriterLock` is more complicated than necessary, especially if you just want the sum.

Comment: Hi erickson, I read you example and at first look it looks great.
But this will not work for me, since I need for this program to be compatible with Java 1.7 and I see that LongAccumulator is present from Java 1.8.

So how to achieve what I need and so it works in Java 1.7?

Comment: @Xyster You can use `AtomicLong` (or `AtomicInteger`) instead. It may not perform quite as well as `LongAccumulator` under high contention, but it will still be better than locking around `HashMap` updates. Note that Java 7 reached end-of-life over a year ago, so obtaining security patches, etc., could be expensive.

Comment: Isn't read lock enough when one of the N threads (that just increase the counter of a particular key/value pair enough) since each each of the N threads will alway work with one and the same key-value pair in the hashmap, so there aren't multiple N threads that work with the same key-value pair meaning there's no thread concurrency there from the perspective of a single key-value pair?
And only the thread X which reads all values and resets them after reading is concurrent with each of the N threads,meaning I require a write lock there. Regarding try-finally,I agree with that and will add it.

Comment: @Xyster No, it's not. Multiple threads could insert a new key concurrently during initialization, for example; that can alter shared state of the table. `HashMap` isn't designed for concurrent use. Why are you so desperate to salvage it when there's a faster, easier alternative that actually works?

Comment: I see your point, so in `put()` method of MMLCounter I would have to replace read lock with write lock. And read lock would then only remain in `increaseCounter()` method and that should work. My key concern here is performance, so from that perspective in the scenario I described, you think it's better to use `AtomicInteger` instead of `ReentrantReadWriteLock` as I described above (plus replacing read lock with write lock in `put` method)?

Comment: @Xyster If performance is important, and you need only the sum of counts, use `AtomicInteger`. You don't need `ReadWriteLock` (or any lock) if you do this---`AtomicInteger` has an increment operation that is threadsafe without it. This will give more accurate rate measurements than a weakly consistent map, and should perform far better than any map with necessary synchronization around it. When you can, update to Java 8 and use `LongAccumulator` which could be even faster.

Comment: OK. In the meanwhile I tried running both versions of program and using `LongAccumulator` really gives much better results then `ReadWriteLock` in combination with `HashMap`. I will try to make update to Java 8 in my production environment, and if not possible, I will then use `AtomicInteger` with Java 7.

Comment: After some thinking I it seems I will need to have multiple counters with multiple values each modified by all threads. I updated my initial question with new code, could you please check section "AFTER 2nd MODIFICATION" and give me a comment? Thank you. :)

Comment: @Xyster With your new revision, the `synchronized` declaration on the methods of `MMLCounter`, together with the fact that you don't modify the `HashMap` after the `Executor` is created, is enough to make your program safe. You should remove all of the read-write lock usage and the `volatile` keyword from fields of `MMLCounter`. That stuff is unnecessary because you `synchronize` the methods that modify state. Then you will have something close to what I suggested with `AtomicInteger` or except that now you are making changes to *two* counters atomically (`total` and `failed`).

Comment: In synchronized functions I added writeLock to prevent that at the same time one thread change total/failed variables through `increaseCounter`,and another thread changes those values by `getCountAndReset`.Synchronized function only means that same function cannot be called concurrently on the same object,but other synconized function can be called and modify the values;right?The other writeLock I placed in thread where I get the count,as I want to achieve that when I'm getting the count I would get snapshot of all counters at the same time,not counter value at the time I access it in the loop

Comment: Sorry, after some more reading I now see that only one synchronized method of a class can be concurrently executed on a object, and restriction is not to the one method. So I will remove writeLock from MMLCounter, along with volatile, but it still need write/read lock the other places to achive whole HashMap is read and reset as an atomic operation, right?

Comment: @Xyster No, you don't need to lock access around the `HashMap` as long as it is not modified after the threads that access it are created. In this case, all additional threads that access the map are started by creating the `Executor`, all map modifications are complete before starting the `Executor`, so the correct state of the `HashMap` is visible to all of those threads. Modifying the *value* objects stored in the map requires a memory barrier, provided by `synchronized` methods here, but you are no longer modifying the `HashMap` itself.

Comment: I'm not certain if we understand each other.Say I have 2 key-value pairs in `HashMap`.To simplify things, values in those pairs are 1 and 5.I iterate through `HashMap` and for each value in it I call `getCountAndReset()`.During first loop iteration, for 1st key-value pair I fetch value 1.Then before next iteration and fetching of 2nd value, another thread calls `increaseCounter` on that value, changing it from 5 to 6.Then second iteration fetches the value of the 2nd key-value pair and this is 6.This is something I want to prevent.Instead fetch all values as they were when I fetched 1st value.

Comment: @Xyster Okay, then a weakly-consistent iteration of the map will not do. You could use one read-write lock. Acquire the write-lock when iterating over map. Acquire read-lock when getting a counter from the map. The methods in `MMLCounter` still need to be `synchronized`.

Comment: Yes, so in the current code above I just remove from class `MMLCounter` volatile from class member variables, and remove the all write-read lock in the same class, and leave method `synchronized` as they already are. Everything else (in `MMLGenerator` class and `main` method) remains as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need `volatile`, without which there is no guarantee that other threads will see the change; java may (and usually does) cache the value locally in another thread, so changing it locally won't make any difference on other threads waiting for it.

For example, this line:

```
this.MMLCounterLocked = true;
```

is useless without the field being `volatile`.

---

Why are you trying to implement your own locks? Just use java's locking by synchronizing on a static field or a static method.

Comment: Hi Bohemian, first, sorry for variable names not following Java convention. I program in different languages (Java, C, C++, C#, Python, Perl, Bash, TTCN, etc.) so sometimes I need a bit of warm-up to remember convention and rules for each language. Anyway, I put in my question modified code which uses `ReentrantReaderWriterLock`, along two additional questions. What do you think and could you answer the additional questions for more clarification?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to utilize a locking scheme that allows multiple readers and exclusive access for one writer, such as `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock`, rather than try to bake your own synchronization mechanism.

[The docs say](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html)

> A ReadWriteLock maintains a pair of associated locks, one for
>   read-only operations and one for writing. The read lock may be held
>   simultaneously by multiple reader threads, so long as there are no
>   writers. The write lock is exclusive.

Comment: Hi Rob, that was exactly what I needed;  didn't know about ReadWriteLock mechanism until now. Thank you. I put in my question modified code which uses `ReentrantReaderWriterLock`, along two additional questions. What do you think and could you comment on two additional questions I posted?

Answer (score -1):

Combining what rob and erickson have said: 
Use a `ConcurrentHashMap` this is thread-safe. 
Use a `ReentrantReaderWriterLock`, let all of the threads that are making edits to the map grab the `ReadLock` so they can edit all at the same time. The read side of the lock is a shared lock. Then the thread that needs a consistent view of the entire map should use the `WriteLock` to gain exclusive access to the map.
The reason that you need `ConcurrentHashMap` is so that all edits to the map including new entries will be seen by all threads. Using the read side of the `ReentrantReaderWriterLock` here is not sufficient.
The reason that you should use the `ReentrantReaderWriterLock` is so when thread X needs exclusive access to the map it can have it, by using the writer side of the lock.
The big problem here is in `increaseCounter` there is a dependency that is not guaranteed to be atomic. You get the value then you increment it. What happens when two threads call this method and both get the same value, then increase it. If this is a bank account and someone lost a penny over the race-condition, well.... you get the idea. There is an invariant here that is not upheld and needs some more fine-grain atomicity. Consider using an `AtomicInteger` as the value side, or check out all of the great classes in the `Atomic` package that offers single variables with atomic actions.

Comment: Hi Imposter, I put in my question modified code which uses `ReentrantReaderWriterLock`, along two additional questions. Didn't use ConcurrentHashMap because I'm not sure if I really need it. Do you think that is enough of should I and why additionally use `ConcurrentHashMap` and why in regards to the two additional questions I posted?

Comment: I updated my answer. If it helps feel free to up-vote it!

Comment: IncreaseCounter is assured to be atomic because when each N thread calls this function it will call it for a different key.So each N thread will work with a different key-value pair,meaning two N threads never can read and then increase the same value.You are also saying that using read lock is not enough to asssure changes of values in HashMap made in one thread are visible in another thread,and @erickson in his answer wrote the opposite,to quote him:"No, Lock acquisition does synchronize with other threads, and changes by other threads that happen before the lock is acquired will be visible"

Comment: IncreaseCounter is not atomic. It does not happen in one step. It takes several operations for it to happen. When any future maintainer makes a subtle change to your code allowing more than one thread to access a key, value pair. Then it is broken. Clever reasoning about synchronization will often lead to failure. The reason that the read side of the lock is not enough to ensure visibility is that if you are making changes to the map while holding a read lock, other threads can be changing it at the same time because it is shared. The reason for the RW lock is to give thread X exclusive access